# Нулевой суффикс или суффикс Н при образовании прилагательных от существительных

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, грамматика

В чем **смысловая разница** прилагательных с суффиксом ***Н*** и с **нулевым** суффиксом, например: ***беззвучный, бездетный, но безусый.***

Особенно интересен этот вопрос по отношению **к паронимам**, которые могут отличаться как **по смыслу, так и по стилю**: безлесый и безлесный, безликий и безличный, злоязыкий и злоязычный, многоязыкий и многоязычный.

Можно ли решить этот вопрос, ориентируясь не только на словари, но и **на соответствие** смысла и грамматической формы?

**Большой толковый** словарь русского языка:

**ЗЛОЯЗЫКИЙ**, -ая, -ое; злоязык, -а, -о. **Разг. = Злоязычный.** З-ая соседка.

**КОСНОЯЗЫЧНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -чен, -чна, -чно. 1. Страдающий косноязычием. Он очень косноязычен. 2. Невнятный, неясный (о речи). 3. Изложенный, написанный невыразительно, с языковыми ошибками. Некоторые сочинения были примитивны и косноязычны. Косноязычно, нареч. Говорить к.

**МНОГОЯЗЫЧНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -чен, -чна, -чно. 1. Состоящий из людей, говорящих на разных языках. М-ое собрание. М-ая толпа. // Звучащий на разных языках. М. говор. М-ая речь. 2. Составленный на нескольких языках. М. словарь.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://rusgram.narod.ru/760-790.html&ved=2ahUKEwjDrML9qoyFAxWERvEDHSI-BJEQFnoECCYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3f49N-o4Q7aC3W1Me7zpTX